# ImageMagick cache resource exhausted

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I use PHP and Imagick extension for resize a photo (about 5000x7000):

```php
$img = new Imagick($fn);
$img->thumbnailImage($width, 0);
```

It works for `$width` is 800, 900 ... 1300,
but it crashes for 1400 and 1600: `cache resources exhausted /app/photo.jpg' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/4083`.

I assumed it depends on the width and the result image size.
And googling for the error text confirmed my guesses.
They advise to increase memory limits in ImageMagick config.

But!
I tried to create image with the width is 2000 and it worked correctly!

1400, 1600, 1800 - fail.
1900, 2000, 2100... - success.

I'm lost.

Comment: I think it depends upon the file size not dimensions.

Comment: @fmw42, yes, but file size depends on dimensions ) original file is fixed and proportion is fixed

Comment: What are the dimensions and file sizes for the files you are using? Please be specific. If JPG, then when read they will be decompressed and be much larger.

Comment: @fmw42 I use one original file with dimension 5000x7000

Comment: How are you making the smaller sizes? If you load the image to crop it, you are loading the whole file.

Comment: Are you just using thumbnail to make it smaller?  Do I understand correctly that one size fails, but larger sizes do not?

Comment: @fmw42, yes just proportional resize. Resize to 1200 works, to 1600 doesn't work, to 2000 works again

Comment: That does not make sense to me. What version of Imagick and what version of ImageMagick is it using? Perhaps it is some PHP issue. If you resize using PHP exec() with a command line call does it work?

Answer (score 14):

Increase the amount of resources that ImageMagick may use. You can control how many resources ImageMagick may use by editing the `policy.xml` file. See [the documentation](https://imagemagick.org/script/security-policy.php) on security policy.

On my (Debian Linux) system the configuration is located at `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`. See [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php) for different locations on various operating systems.

I changed the following settings to `2GiB` to get rid of the error, you may need different ones, depending on your needs and system resources. Take a look at the documentation.

```
<policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="2GiB"/>
<policy domain="resource" name="map" value="2GiB"/>
```

Comment: If my answer answered your question @androkettle, please consider accepting it!